# Were there any test flying incidents during which the pilots managed to escape the plane?

Tags: jet, flight-testing

I am only asking about flight testing civilian jets, not military ones. I know that all test pilots have to be equipped with a parachute, so I wonder was there any incident where the test pilots and test engineers had to leave the plane during the flight, and managed to reach the earth? Alive or dead.

Comment: Escaping with a parachute is always difficult, and specially difficult in fast airplanes, like jets, without the help of an ejection seat. It is, however, not impossible (the exceptional case of Gary Powers and the U-2 is a good example) but it's rare...

Comment: Is the OP asking for bailouts only?  If no: I remember reading in "Yeager", the autobiography of Chuck Yeager, about 2 situations while he was a test pilot at Muroc AFB: the first was a training flight in an F-104 with 2 test pilots where the engine went out on takeoff and one pilot ejected, the other stayed (turns out if the second ejected he would have died, and if the first stayed he would have died), both surviving; the latter is Yeager's ejection from an NF-104 while commandant of ARPS (http://www.kalimera.org/nf104/stories/stories_12.html).  Don't know of a database for these though.

Comment: Whether inside the plane or outside, dead or alive, the crew all manage to reach the earth after each and every test flight. Gravity can be cruel that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do civilian space ships count?

In the [VSS Enterprise crash](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/VSS_Enterprise_crash)  the captain survived. The plane broke up around him and he was able to unstrap his seat after which his parachute automatically deployed. The co-pilot died in the crash.

Comment: You can see a bit more details about the accident and how the pilot got out on this [video](https://youtu.be/B6fmNLFx564?t=37s).

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  Here is a (long) video of a test pilot spinning a Bonanza with a cockpit POV.  He ends up bailing out.  Skip to [11:30](https://youtu.be/1puk4GoFXZI) to watch the entry.

Ovbiously not a jet, but maybe it's close to what you're looking for.

Comment: I think you need to skip to 12:30?

Comment: "Video unavailable: the video is private"

Comment: YouTube something like "bonanza spin" or similar.  The video is widely available.

Answer (score 7):

During the early development flight tests of the Challenger, an aircraft was trapped in a deep stall. Two crew members bailed out, but the final crew member did not survive the bail out.

http://www.check-six.com/Crash_Sites/Canadair-CGCGRX.htm

Answer (score 3):

In the remote-controlled crash of a 727, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Boeing_727_crash_experiment, the crew (and some camera-men) left by parachute...

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [the Aviation Safety Network](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19650512-0):

> The HansaJet prototype was in the midst of stall configuration tests
> at 22,000 [feet,] when it attained an extreme angle of attack resulting
> in a superstall. The airplane then entered an uncontrollable flat
> spin. Two crew members were able to parachute to safety.